# Python Cloud Logging on GCF: Logs isn't being parsed with this setup. Why?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-functions

```
import logging
from google.cloud import logging as cloud_logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

# Configure Cloud Logging
cloud_client = cloud_logging.Client()
# cloud_client.setup_logging()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(cloud_client)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

With or without `setup_logging()`, gen1 or gen2, I cannot see any logs I'm parsing.
What am I doing wrong?